# Compact USB hub for a smartphone host with power delivery to the phone

Tags: usb, hub

I am looking for a USB hub to connect mouse/keyboard simultaneously to my phone while powering/charging the phone ("power delivery"). I would like to be able to connect one or two other peripherals, so 4-5 ports including the phone connector would be ideal.

Ideally it should also be possible to use it without mains adapter too, for instance, plugging it into a computer to power it, even if it reduced performance, but this isn't essential.

[Reading a bit more](http://www.scientificcomputing.com/blogs/2015/01/go-fascinating-facts-about-usb-otg), I think it needs to support USB Power Delivery v2.0 and have a mains power option.

Comment: I have used Anker products for many years, and I have an Anker PowerPort myself. I have to say that they are great products and I would definitely recommend the one you have listed.

Comment: @BG_Programmer Thank you. So that definitely has the hub functionality (connects peripherals to the phone) while charging/powering the phone?

Comment: It cannot be used without a mains adaptor, but apart from that, it has the hub functionality.

Comment: Ah, I think that maybe I have misunderstood your question. The Anker PowerPort simple connects with one cable to the mains and you can then charge your devices by connecting to its output ports. Is that what you are after?

Comment: I want to use a mouse and keyboard with my phone at the same time (can connect one or the other as the phones typically have one USB port). As powering both accessories and a hub would be a load on the battery, I am looking for a mains powered hub that will power/charge the phone as well as powering mouse/keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not think that the powerport will work for that scenario

Comment: Here is one for USB type-C you can get a converter, or a phone with C type, then : https://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-usb-type-c-to-hdmi-multiport-adapter-with-power-delivery-white/5577934.p?skuId=5577934

Comment: Do you still need this answered?  I can type up an answer using the hub you posted, but if you've already figured it out, then it's not worth the time.

Comment: Yes please, if you could!

Answer (score 1):

the best one I have found so far is LETSCOM USB C Hub, 8 in 1 USB C Adapter with Wireless Charger, 4K HDMI, USB C Power Delivery, 3 USB 3.0 Ports, SD/TF Card Reader, Compatible for USB Type C Devices not sure if it does what you need but its pretty efficient obviously depending on the phone and you'd need to check that it is compatible with your device